# How to visible image in list items

Tags: android

Hello I am using List view.  When I click the delete button I want that time only show the delete image Initially I invisible the deleteimage(redminus mark) .http://pasteboard.co/1yJZyUz7.png   http://pasteboard.co/1yK2BsYb.png  and i try the code

```
public class ViewBudget extends FragmentActivity  {
     boolean editmode=false;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle)
    {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.viewbug);
        getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.main1);
        TextView ctitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.customtitlebar);

        //asyncktask
        new ImageDownload().execute("");


        lv = (ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);

        //  lv.setAdapter(new IconicAdapter(this));
        Button del=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
        del.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub                    
                editmode=true;
            notifyDataSetChanged(); 
            }

        });


        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v,int position, long id) 
            {

        });

    }



    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    class IconicAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {
        Activity context;

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        IconicAdapter(Activity context) {
            super(context, R.layout.viewbudget, str2);
            this.context = context;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
            View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.viewbudget, null);
            TextView label = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.label);
            ImageView deli=(ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
            TextView delll=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.textView10);

            if(editmode) {
             deli.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        else {
            deli.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }


          }
```

But not get visible after clicking the Delete button. Thanks.

Comment: debug your code and see did `editmode` changes.

Comment: As a side note, normally, you shouldn't suppress warnings. It's may cause programming errors, like wrong type casting etc.

Answer (score 3):

notifyDataSetChanged() will not work here , notifyDataSetChanged() only work when the size of data(the array or ArrayList) is changed.

You need to set new Adapter to the listview, to hold the scrolling position you can use the following code -

```
//collecting current scroll pos
int selectedPos = lv.getFirstVisiblePosition();
View v = lv.getChildAt(0);
int scrollOffset = (v == null) ? 0 : v.getTop();

//reset new adapter
lv.setAdapter(new IconicAdapter(this));

//restoring scroll pos
lv.setSelectionFromTop(selectedPos, scrollOffset);
```

Comment: just u go to below see the chat and click

Answer (score 0):

Can you change this:

```
deli.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

into:

```
deli.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

**Note:** Do not set any visibility in your .xml file for the attribute.